# GAE, JDO: Add, Move & Delete entities of ordered list

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Hi i have a parent entity say A which has list of child entities say List<B> children.

I need the order of child entities to be maintained since its important for my application.

The way i have done it is using:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships

How Ordered Collections Maintain Their Order.

`@Persistent`

@Element(dependent = "true")

@Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="list-ordering", value="index ASC"))

private List objects;

Now i add to list using:

`newObj.setIndex(0);`

for (int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++) {

objList.get(i).setIndex(i + 1);

}

objList.add(newObj);

Move using:

`if (direction.equalsIgnoreCase("up")) {`

objList.get(index).setIndex(index - 1);

objList.get(index - 1).setIndex(index);

}

else if (direction.equalsIgnoreCase("down")) {

objList.get(index).setIndex(index + 1);

objList.get(index + 1).setIndex(index);

}

And delete using:

`for (int i = index + 1; i < objList.size(); i++) {`

objList.get(i).setIndex(i - 1);

}

objList.remove(index);

Is this the right way to do it? Add & Move seem to work. But Delete behaves weirdly. Random objs get deleted and the list is in completely inconsistent state!

GAE: 1.7.2

DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.0.m2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove at an index only makes real sense for an **indexed** list (i.e the standard JDO List) and you're not using that. When you call that with DataNucleus and an RDBMS an exception is thrown. Obviously GAE didn't get around to such niceties, but then logic would suggest it. Removing something from an ordered list really ought to call *remove(Object)*.

Moving objects around using setting of this index column may work ... at the next time they are read in; the only thing that the "ordering" clause does is order things at the point they are read in.

Answer (score 0):

try to call objList.remove() before adjusting all the indexes.

Comment: Did that. Even tried not changing indexes and just remove the object from list and persist but still things aren't working. The persist happens in transaction if that info helps.